# How do I clean my wood floors?

Tags: cleaning, wood

How do I get rid of these spots and streaks on my floors? Just moved into a house and thought this was just dirt but its not getting removed with a mop and Bona hardwood cleaner, I'm a little nervous about using something abrasive—not sure what the wood is made of and how they were finished.

This is how it looks like:

[image: picture of the floor]

[image: picture of the floor]

[image: picture of the floor]

Comment: It looks like the wood paint was not applied uniformly. If you do not want to get your hands "dirty", ask for the opinion (and maybe the work) of a professional. Also, I think I notice some damage (scratches etc.) to the wood. You might want them repaired also.

Comment: If the floor was sealed with those marks already on the floor, then one remedy would be to get it all stripped off and sanded, and start over (if it really matters).

Comment: Is it natural wood, or laminate painted to look like wood? Do you want to keep the aspect of wood, or not? Because one solution is to hire a professional to slightly remove the top layer and repaint everything to your desires. But the new paint might not reproduce the wood fibers, if it is not natural wood.

Answer (score 1):

The first picture looks like stain is missing from the wood, and the second is the texture of the wood. That looks like actual ridges, not something you can clean away.

Answer (score 0):

In the second photo, notice that the scratches end at the edge of the board.

These were deliberately designed that way so they will have the trendy old-fashioned look that of course everyone wanted to have back when it was installed.

[Villa Barcelona Reclaimed Prefinished French Oak Rubi Wirebrushed Engineered Hardwood Flooring](https://www.lowes.ca/product/hardwood-flooring/villa-barcelona-reclaimed-prefinished-french-oak-rubi-wirebrushed-engineered-hardwood-flooring-5-in-7-in-x-12-in-330908239)
for instance looks like this:
[image]

Notice the wonderful combination of both lateral *and* circular-saw marks.

> … meticulously sculpted by skilled artisans to offer the distinction, beauty and warmth of hardwood flooring.
> Special tools are utilized to add to the beauty of the wood surfaces,…

Yours is likely "engineered" (laminated plywood) or "laminated" (vaneer), and so, unlike the actual old-fashioned floorboards, it can't be sanded and refinished every few decades.
(But I'm sure a flooring store will gladly sell you whatever the latest trend is these days so you can completely replace it.)